# Choosing between adding a maven dependency vs. copying the one class I need

Tags: clean-code, dependencies, maven

My project can benefit from a bit of code from the Apache commons-math3 project.  Specifically, my math heavy application would benefit from using the FastMath class which avoids using extremely precise, but slow, native methods.

I have a choice here.

I could add an entire maven dependency for this one class (FastMath) or I could cherry pick this single class (+tests) and copy/paste it into my project.

What factors would come into play if you were to make this decision?  What factors are most important to the long term health and usability of the project.

Would you prefer to add an external dependency?  Would you prefer to add (i.e. copy/paste) a new class.

Comment: I wouldn't be suprised if that one class uses more, which uses more, which uses more

Comment: @RichardTingle That would seem to be the common case, but in this particular example the class / methods I need can be cherry picked.

Comment: @Ivan: Is it really such a burden to add an *entire* Maven dependency? Is the jar actually so large as to cause significant application bloat? I'm really curious why there seems to be such reluctance to just add one more entry to a POM file.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Part of the reason I ask is because I that I may be overly hesitant to add dependencies.  I've grown far more hesitant in the last year or so because some of our project have hit "jar hell".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for your personal use, or if this is some sort of proof-of-concept project not intended for sustained use by the general public, do whatever is the least amount of work (probably cut and paste).

If this is intended for general distribution, and/or the application will be in existence for some time, a reference may be better, since the folks using the app may wish to update it, e.g. if any bugs are found and a new version is released.

Comment: I appreciate mentioning a possible new version.  I hadn't considered that in this case because this is Math.  But, considering version for the "in general" case makes good sense.

Comment: Sometimes even math logic can have bugs (see the [Pentium FDIV defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)), or there could be bugs unrelated to the math, such as a memory leak or security vulnerability.